# How to enable printer settings over Jetdirect on HP 4100N

Tags: networking, printer, hp-laserjet

I have a HP 4100N printer and I am using it over network.

Previously I was able to access the printer settings over internet, but now the only thing visible is Device Info and Networking. I can connect to the web server and I can set all the network related settings, but that's not what I want.

There should be a supplies, config, print info, etc. page, what are not visible now.

Can you tell me what setting should I set to enable this printer config page on the webserver?

The printer is a HP 4100N and the network card is J4169A (Jetdirect 610n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, golden solution, once you run out of ideas:

Turn off - Wait a minute - Turn on

Now the missing tabs are present in the web-server.

Answer (score 0):

> Previously I was able to access the printer settings over internet

What do you mean by this, what have you done since you where **previously** able to see what you needed? Updated drivers/firmware?

Comment: No, I've just switched on and off the printer every day. Now I don't see the options.